# run interactive program from Window CMD script

Tags: windows, script, batch-file, command-line

I have a CMD script to run on Windows. It does  `DEL`, but the shell would ask "Are you sure?"
How do I make the script answer 'YES', or better yet, just does a silent `DEL`  ?

Thanks

Comment: Questions about the use and invocation of utilities provided with your computer belong on SuperUser.  There's no programming here.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes all you have to do is read the help:

> ```
> C:\>help del
> ```
>
> ## Deletes one or more files.
>
> ```
> DEL [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names ERASE [/P] [/F] [/S]
>     [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names
> ```
>
> `names`         Specifies a list of one or more files or directories.
>                   Wildcards may be used to delete multiple files. If a
>                   directory is specified, all files within the directory
>                   will be deleted.
>
> `/P`            Prompts for confirmation before deleting each file.
>
> `/F`            Force deleting of read-only files.
>
> `/S`            Delete specified files from all subdirectories.
>
> **`/Q`            Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard**
>
> `/A`           Selects files to delete based on attributes
>
> If Command Extensions are enabled `DEL` and `ERASE` change as follows:
>
> The display semantics of the `/S` switch are reversed in that it shows
>   you only the files that are deleted, not the ones it could not find.

Comment: I tried /Q (which is the answer I got from the Windows IRC), but it didn't work! This is on Windows8, running PowerShell, btw

Comment: @user1508893: Your question clearly says you're running `CMD`, not PowerShell.  So which is it?  (Furthermore, with PowerShell you'd be using `remove-item` not `DEL`)

Comment: @user1508893 `del` is aliased to `Remove-Item` in PowerShell, so that's fine. `Remove-Item` does not prompt by default, but will if you don't include `-Recurse` when targetting a directory. You can also force it not to prompt with `-Confirm:$false` though, again, you need `-Recurse` if targetting a directory.